# python conditional operator must end with else in comprehensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-operator

Do comprehensions need to end with an else, if I am using else if?

examples:

```
 a = ['tuple' if type(x)==tuple else 'int' if type(x)==int else 'float'
     if type(x)==float for x in [1, 2.5, (5,6), {}]]
print(a)
```

It won't work and will make `expected else after if expression`, but this will work:

```
a = ['tuple' if type(x)==tuple else 'int' if type(x)==int else 'float'
     if type(x)==float else None for x in [1, 2.5, (5,6), {}]]
print(a)
```

output: `['int', 'float', 'tuple', None]`
after all I don't want the None there.

Comment: The conditional operator is not related to comprehensions. But yes, they have to have an `else`

Comment: That is just the python ternary operator. Also don't use `type(x) == int`, but `isinstance(x, int)`

Comment: Use the generator's filtering option: `for x in [...] if <condition>`

Comment: @Barmar then I will need to calculate the things twice? at the end.. in mylist if type(x) in [float, int, list, etc], so any iteration will pass more conditional operators than it needs to.

Comment: Yes. So it might be better to use a regular loop with `if` statements instead of a list comprehension.

Comment: You're already calculating it multiple times, by using `type(x)` in each conditional expression. With a loop you can assign that to a variable and test it with `if/elif/...`